Error message in a custom validator in a mongoose Schema
i am a total begginer. I am trying to send a specific error message in password and password confirm validator in a mongoose schema.
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  

 password:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide a password.'],
        minlength: 8
    },

 passwordConfirm:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please confirm your password.'],
        validate:{
            validator: 
            function (el) {
            return el === this.password; //expectation
            },
            message: 'Password and password confirm was not the same' //something like this
          }
        },
});

when i test a user sign in request with different password and password confirm, i get the error message from my catch block in the router function, which is an overall error message that says that sth is wrong. But it could be anything. Isn't there a simple way to just let the user know whats the issue like typed above? 'Password and password confirm was not the same' ?
Thank you
EDIT: Sign in code block
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../Models/usersModel');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/userSignIn', async (req , res) => {
    try{
       const data = new User ({
           name: req.body.name,
           email: req.body.email,
           password: req.body.password,
           passwordConfirm: req.body.passwordConfirm
       })
   
       const newUser = await data.save(); 
       res.status(200).json(newUser);
       console.log('New user signed in succesfully.');

    }catch{
        res.status(400).json({
            message:'Something went wrong while trying to sign in a new user.'
        });
    };
   });

   module.exports = router;


Show the signin code block where you have used try-catch block

I edited the coded. Updated with my sign in code block. Thnak you!

Hi, Have you been able to see the answer, would like to know if it has helped you. For any clarifications, please do post.

@user25543263, So you want a custom validation message to be shown if password & passwordConfirm field mismatched while request is coming to this router.post('/userSignIn',... route.Right? Upon you confirmation I will write my answer editing your code.So check this comment & confirm.

@user25543263, Another point , does usersModel mapped with userSchema ? If so then where are the other fields?

In your catch block you are not catching the exceptionVar which will hold an object detailing the errors. Simply modify to catch(err){ console.log(err)}. Now the errors will be accessible in the variable named err. See Catch binding. You can then decide if you want to send something from the err object to your users in the response.

Thank you, everyone! You all helped in different ways, because you gave me several info.
const password = req.body.password;
const passwordConfirm = req.body.passwordConfirm;
try{
if (password === passwordConfirm){...}
this is what I came up with. It works fine for now. I will try other solutions that you proposed though. Thank you!

Hi, Noted the solution you arrived, one thing to ask is that will that solution trigger the error message defined in the schema, for e.g. When the passwords mismatch, will it trigger automatically the message you have already given in the schema - "'Password and password confirm was not the same'.

Please make use of error.errors object.
The error is a ValidationError object, and error.errors is a ValidatorError object.
Whenever the validation fails, error.errors will have the validation messages in its respective keys. Please note, error.errors will have messages only for the keys failed validation, the keys passed validation will not be available in it. Therefore nullity is to checked.
Please see the code below doing the same. The schema and model objects in the question have been used here.
server.js
app.get('/:password/:confirmation', async (req, res, next) => {
  const password = req.params.password;
  const confirmation = req.params.confirmation;

  try {
    // For testing, deleting previous entries if any
    await PasswordModel.deleteMany(); 
    
    // creating a new document
    const newpassword = new PasswordModel({
      password: password,
      passwordConfirm: confirmation,
    });
    
    // saving the document will trigger validations
    await newpassword.save();
    res.send('password confirmed and saved.');

  } catch (error) {
    // checking for the validation errors,
    // and passing it to Express so that Express will take
    // care of the error and send to the client
     const validationErrors = new Array(
     error.errors?.password?.message,
     error.errors?.passwordConfirm?.message).filter((i) => i);

     if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
        next(validationErrors);
     } else {
        // passing other errors if any to Express
        next(error);
     }
  }
});

Running the server
node server.js

Testing using curl
% curl http://localhost:3000/123/12           
["Path `password` (`123`) is shorter than the minimum allowed length (8).","Password and password confirm was not the same"]                                                                       

% curl http://localhost:3000/123/123          
["Path `password` (`123`) is shorter than the minimum allowed length (8)."]                      

% curl http://localhost:3000/12345678/1234567 
["Password and password confirm was not the same"]                                

% curl http://localhost:3000/12345678/12345678
password confirmed and saved.

Citation:
Validation Errors

Hi, Please see if this post helps you.
